# count how many a combination occurs in a list

Tags: python, list

I created a list by doing this:

```
list3= [zip(Indiener1, Indiener2)]
```

Both elements are long lists of names.

But as a third element in the small combined list I want the number of times the combination of names occurs in the whole `list3` as I have to do calculations with that number.

I tried `list3.count()` but that function only wanted to take one item.

How can I do this?

Comment: ...what? Could you give (short) examples of input and expected and actual output?

Comment: Did you check the [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class?

Comment: can you provide expected input and expected output

Comment: You want to count occurences of name pairs ?

Comment: Okay, Indiener1 and Indiener2 are lists of names. list3 looks like this: list3((john,elvis),(john,elvis),(john,peter)) expected output is like ((john, elvis, 2), (john,elvis, 2),(john, peter,1)) I looked at collections.Counter as well but it didnt worked out for me so far.

Comment: what about `("foo","bar"),("bar","foo")` are they considered the same?

Comment: ("foo","bar"),("bar","foo") are considered the same yes.

Comment: No built-in Python structure looks like `list3((john,elvis),(john,elvis),(john,peter))`. Please **edit the question** with the appropriate information.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

list1=["a","b","d","b"]
list2=["5","u","55","u"]
list3=zip(list1,list2)

print Counter(list3)
```

it outputs:

```
Counter({('b', 'u'): 2, ('d', '55'): 1, ('a', '5'): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter and reverse the pairings to get `("foo","bar") == ("bar","foo")`:

```
 l1 =["foo","bar","foobar"]
l2 = ["bar","foo","bar"]

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(zip(l1,l2))

for k,v in c.items():
    rev = tuple(reversed(k))
    print("pairing {}  appears {}".format(k,v + c.get(rev,0)))
```

To avoid getting double output `('foo', 'bar')`  and `('bar', 'foo')` you can add rev to a set and check that it has not been seen already:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(zip(l1,l2))
seen = set()
for k, v in c.items():
    rev = tuple(reversed(k))
    if k not in seen:
        seen.add(rev)
        print("pairing {}  appears {} times".format(k,v + c.get(rev,0)))

pairing ('foo', 'bar')  appears 2 times
pairing ('foobar', 'bar')  appears 1 times
```

Comment: thanks, this worked out for me. Tried counter before but don't know what went wrong. This is perfect.

Comment: No worries, I added a set to avoid duplicate output

Answer (score 0):

Since `("foo","bar")` and `("bar","foo")` are considered the same, you have to count on something like `sets`, where order doesn't matter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l1 = ['John', 'Doe', 'Paul', 'Pablo', 'Paul', 'Doe']
>>> l2 = ['Doe', 'John', 'Doe', 'Doe', 'Doe', 'Paul']
>>> print Counter(frozenset(pair) for pair in zip(l1, l2))
Counter({
    frozenset(['Paul', 'Doe']): 3, 
    frozenset(['John', 'Doe']): 2, 
    frozenset(['Doe', 'Pablo']): 1
})
```

You can also sort the pairs before counting, but a `set` makes the purpose more explicit.